# se tarda el servidor

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, datatables, electron

tengo un problema con mi aplicacion, estoy usando mysql para la base de datos y tambien jquery y datatables. Y aveces funciona y aveces no, me refiero a que cuando por ejemplo uso el localhost me carga la tabla correctamente siempre, cuando uso clever cloud aveces me carga correctamente pero muchas veces no, entonces supongo que es por que se tarda haciendo la consulta, necesito seguir usando clever cloud por un tiempo asi que no se como solucionar esto. Estoy trabajando Electron, nodejs y mysql.

Comment: Buenas, serias capaz de responder a la pregunta con esta información?, sin un codigo por detras nos lo pones bastante dificil, nosotros no resolvemos dudas basadas en opiniones, resolvemos dudas que contengan un codigo e investigacion por detras, por ejemplo, que haz intentado?, de que te haz dado cuenta?, cual es el codigo que usas?, tu código contiene errores?, si es asi poner el error, falta mucha información al respecto para poder hacer de esta una pregunta valida en el sitio, considera pasar por el [tour] y leer sobre [ask], tambien te invito a editar la pregunta para complementarla.

Comment: Si disculpa la falta de información, igual yo la pude resolver. La función de jQuery la tenía en un script en el HTML y como se tardaba el servidor en hacer la consulta pues metí la función del jquery en una hoja de Javascript y ya la llamé en el mismo lugar donde la tenía, esto para darle un poco más de tiempo al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

La función de jQuery la tenía en un script en el HTML y como se tardaba el servidor en hacer la consulta pues metí la función del jquery en una hoja de Javascript y ya la llamé en el mismo lugar donde la tenía, esto para darle un poco más de tiempo al servidor.